# Echo all the folder names in a folder

Tags: php

I want to print all the folder names inside a parent folder. The current issue I am facing is, though I have 400+ folders in a folder only 257 are getting printed. Again, this is not at all issue related with permissions.

Please find my code below:

```
    $newdir = "content/";
     $dircnt = 0;
// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($newdir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($newdir)) {
       while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
           $dircnt++;
           if(filetype($newdir. $file) == 'dir') {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($newdir. $file) . "dircnt:"        .$dircnt. "<br>";
          }
       }
       closedir($dh);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does the loop stop, or skip entries?

Comment: @ Bart Friederichs: The loops simply stops as when I echoed something inside while loop, it was getting executed till 259th folder(257 folders along with '.' and '..')

Comment: How do you know the folds' number as 400+,the `$dircnt` variable?then you may place the `$dircnt++;` wrong.

Comment: And what do your logs say?

Comment: try `is_dir` instead of `filetype`

Comment: @Young: I am accessing some remote server using winscp and under properties of the folder it shows me the folder count. Also my application creates one folder in the parent folder but it is not being rendered inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob()` function - returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error.

```
       $filesDirectories = glob($newdir.'*', GLOB_BRACE);
        foreach($filesDirectories as $key=>$file) {
             echo "$file size " . filesize($file) . "\n";               
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use glob:

```
$newdir = "content/";
$dirs = glob($newdir.'*',GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach($dirs as $index=>$dir){
    echo "filename ". $dir." filetype ".filetype($newdir.$dir)." dircnt:".($index+1)."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: It's giving the same result I mentioned.